# Faster query time in pyvisa?

Tags: pyvisa

Is there any way to reduce the time it takes for **pyvisa** to query a value in an instrument and transfer said value to the program?

In my situation I'm working with three oscilloscopes at the same time. They are constantly measuring data and my python program is writing the values to a textfile. After an hour I get a total of 9000 measurements int total (which is just 0,83 measurements/second/oscilloscope).

I've searched in the documentation and I have found that the `query` function has an argument of time, but the argument is just to increase the time of delay.

Anything I might be missing?

The relevant code is as follows:

```code
t_start = time.time()
while ((time.time()-time_run)<=3600.0):#measures for an hour
    meas_x_1 = float(oscilloscope_1.query('meas:vav? chan1'))
    meas_y_1 = float(oscilloscope_1.query('meas:vav? chan2'))
    meas_z_1 = float(oscilloscope_2.query('meas:vav? chan1'))
    
    meas_x_2 = float(oscilloscope_2.query('meas:vav? chan2'))
    meas_y_2 = float(oscilloscope_3.query('meas:vav? chan1'))
    meas_z_2 = float(oscilloscope_3.query('meas:vav? chan2'))
    
    total_meas += 1;
    #print(total_meas)
    file1.write(str(total_meas) + '\t' +str(meas_x_1) + '\t' + str(meas_y_1) + '\t' + str(meas_z_1) + '\t' + str(meas_x_2) + '\t'+ str(meas_y_2) + '\t' + str(meas_z_2) + '\n')
    if(total_meas %  100 == 0):
        print(int(time.time()-time_run)/60)
    #print(total_meas)
```

Some other information about the setup:

- The oscilloscopes are from the: *2000-X* series of *Keysight InfiniiVision*, specifically the *DSO-X 2002A*
- The identification of the instruments are throught *NI MAX* (NI Measurement & Automation Explorer)
- The oscilloscopes are connected to the oscilloscope through a USB cables

Comment: Hard to know. in general no but that doesn't mean there aren't better ways to do it. Can you specify the scopes used, your connection type, the setup of measurement of the scope? it sounds like you're using the scopes like a DMM.

Comment: Hi @Zircatron, essentially yes. I am using the oscilloscope as a DMM. The reason is that it is the only instrument I was taught last year to use with pyvisa in order to automate taking measurements (I'm a student doing my undergrad dissertation for clarification). I'm afraid I added most of the information I know about the setup in the edit. I don't really know the more technical aspects.
Thanks for taking the time to answer and sorry for any etiquette mistakes (I'm kind of new to posting on StackOverflow)

Comment: Hi '@Sergio Pardina', I would like to help, unfortunately scopes can be relatively limited and you might have already hit the limitations. If your scope has segmented memory you might be able to get more captures of what you're looking for but when you try to transfer those captures you will still have gaps in your recording. do you have a github or another place you can share the code?

Comment: Hello again @Zircatron, sorry for answering so late. You're probably right and I hit the limitations so I think I'll try make the most  of the data I have since it is good enough for what I need to do. Thanks for your time and help :)